# Estimate the Number of part files to Write in HDFS from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I want to write a Spark Dataframe in Parquet.snappy format in HDFS. Currently it is creating default 200 part files even if the number of records in the table is less.

Is the any formula available which gives an approx number of part files to be written in HDFS so the read can be faster.

Ideally the part file size should be between 50-200 MB.
I am aware of repartition and coalesce functionality which reduce/increase the number of part files. I am looking for the number on which the dataframe needs to be repartitioned.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you will have as many part files as partitions in your Dataframe.

If you are sure about total data volume you can try to use `coalesce` or `repartition` methods.